# Android App Publishing Keystore Password

Tags: android, eclipse, rsa, keystore, keytool

I'm trying to export a signed android application in eclipse. I make it to the keystore dialog box and am prompted to enter a keystore password. I do not have a password for my keystore. Is there anyway to export an app without a password? If not how do I change my password?

Thanks

EDIT: I left out some important info. My keystore does not require a password to access it. It is the default debug keystore that eclipse uses.

Comment: no, you definitely will need the password. If you don't have it then you'll have to create a new keystore / key. Did you already create your keystore and forget the password? Or have you not created one yet?

Comment: Sorry I was a bit vuage with the question. My keystore does not require a password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you answered your own question:

> It is the default debug keystore that eclipse uses.

Check out the developer docs related to signing for release. You'll need to create a release keystore:
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode

Comment: Ahh I see. I've been following my professors instructions and they were very misleading. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should have been prompted for a password, or entered one as a commandline argument, when creating your keystore. If you just hit enter when prompted to enter a password then you can probably leave it blank in signing, but that is generally a bad idea.

Comment: I did leave it blank at signing. Is there any way to change it so I do have a password?